# Connection error accessing Sage Timberline Accounting with PHP and ODBC on Windows

Tags: php, odbc, sage-erp

I'm trying to connect to a Sage Timberline Accounting database on my Windows 2003 Server using PHP 5.3. I have PHP correctly installed with IIS as fastcgi. I have a system DSN setup in ODBC Manager and correctly configured for the Timberline database.

Here is my PHP script.

```
<?php

$conn = odbc_connect("Timberline ODBC","user", "password");

?>
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Sage Timberline Office][Sage Timberline Office ODBC Driver][DRM File Library]Invalid account name., SQL state 08001 in SQLConnect in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\index.php on line 3

It doesn't matter what valid Timberline username and password combination I try.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is still a question or not...but you do realize that a pervasive SQL connection is to a index file that then has index references to the other information?  Better known as a flat-file database structure.

As such, there is no clean cut way to make the connection.  I am working on a similar problem with bridging my MSSQL server to the Timberline Database and it is not as clean cut as you would think.

Have you tried loading the Timberline Driver onto the webserver or into the application in question for consumption?  Sage has not made it easy for you to access this information at all and if i have my 2 cents to say about this application suite, i would suggest against it at ALL cost.

So far here is a connection string that works, via VS2k5.  It is a DSN string but connection string none the less.  Problem i am having is dissoicating the DSN part from the connection string and getting it to work properly.

```
DSN=<whatever>;uid=<userid>;dbq=<PathToDirectory>;codepage=1252;
maxcolsupport=1536;dictionarymode=0;standardmode=0;shortennames=1;databasetype=1
```

This is supposed to work for ADO, but cant get it to work properly:

```
Provider=MSDASQL.1;Driver={Timberline Data};dbq=<PathToDirectory>;
uid=<userid>;pwd=<password>;codepage=1252
```

Comment: plus uno for recommending against sage.  If a company does not want to provide easy access to connections and apis, and furthermore has little to no documentation, then their ware is already obsolete.  SAGE DEVS I HOPE YOU READ THIS!

Comment: @GoldBishop do you know why codepage is set to 1252 and maxcolsupport to 1536? what if the working driver the options are using Dictionary names without "Use maximum table segment size" and "Shorten field and table names" checkbox remain unticked? will it require different connection string?

Comment: I got it now, that details can be obtained from DSN in the Windows registry, codepage 1252 refers to ANSI standard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) and maxcolsupport is the number of column supported for a table, if it is set to 255 then table like MASTER_JCM_RECORD_1 will be splitted into 2 tables, MASTER_JCM_RECORD_1_1 and MASTER_JCM_RECORD_1_2 (https://support.na.sage.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=17866&sliceId=1)

Comment: @sigeje Sorry for the slow response, school is in and students are emailing me constantly.  I will defer to your investigation, as the detailed information from the project I referred to has long since gone under the bridge.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that IIS is running as a user that has access to the Timberline directory (the path you have set for the dbq parameter in your connection string).

Change the "Log On As" setting of your IIS service.  Again, make sure you use an account that has access to the network location of your timberline data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code to build connection strings for use with ADO.NET to connect to Timberline. You can use it as a template for building a connection string in PHP. Also, consider using the default "Timberline Data Source" DSN.

```
public class TimberlineConnectionStringBuilder
{
        public static string GetConnectionString(string username, string password, string dataFilePath, string dsn)
        {
            var builder = new OdbcConnectionStringBuilder { Dsn = dsn };
            builder.Add("uid", username);
            builder.Add("dbq", dataFilePath);
            builder.Add("codepage", 1252);
            builder.Add("dictionarymode", 0);
            builder.Add("standardmode", 1);
            builder.Add("maxcolsupport", 1536);
            builder.Add("shortenames", 0);
            builder.Add("databasetype", 1);
            builder.Add("pwd", password);
            return builder.ConnectionString;
        }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to do a limit?

Comment: an sql limit on the returned set from a select... does not look like the timberline odbc driver implements LIMIT

Comment: The Timberline ODBC driver has a lot of limitations.  I backup copies of key tables (e.g. JCM_MASTER__JOB) to SQL Server using SSIS and query against SQL Server.  This works for most use cases since people don't normally need "up to the minute" data. I can simply do a nightly backup and query against that.

Comment: Yes I use anterra data warehouse to sync all tables, but am needing to connect directly in some situation within my code. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I recently spent a lot of time making this work; I found a few dozen posts of folks that were not able to connect; but very few answers. These are my learnings:

Sage Timberline Office, now named Sage CRE 300, uses a Pervasive SQL Database.  Their upgrade path is towards SQL Server by end of 2019.

There are 2 ODBC connections you can use to connect:

**1. Use the native Pervasive ODBC drivers**

The ODBC drivers are included in the free Pervasive Client. Just search for the latest install.

Both, 32 & 64 bit drivers are included.

PHP lets you connect through a simple connection string like: `odbc_connect("Driver={Pervasive ODBC Interface};ServerName=myserver;ServerDSN=mydsn;", "", "", SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);`

Pervasive has lots of good up-to-date documentation available.

One giant downside: you can *only* read data. Sage fields are internally marked and need a password to allow updating. Sage will not provide the password; even for pay. (I tried).

**2. Use the Sage provided ODBC driver**

The only way to get the ODBC driver is by installing a Sage Client. (But read on, as you probably don't want to do this anyway).

The Sage ODBC driver is called Timberline Data, and a Simba product.

The driver is only available in 32 bit version.

The driver does more than interface:
 - Pervasive table and field names are short; this ODBC driver acts like a translator providing long names. There are 2 versions of these long names. Decide what you want to use and stick to it.
 - The Sage ODBC driver allows updating of fields. Not all fields; just the fields that Sage allows you to change. If updating is critical, then this is your *only* option.

This is the official connection string, and how you would use it in PHP:

```
odbc_connect("Driver={Timberline Data};UID=Mark;PWD=sage123!;DBQ=C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Sage\Timberline Office\Data\Construction Sample Data;CODEPAGE=1252;DictionaryMode=0;StandardMode=1;MaxColSupport=1536;", "", "", SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
```

I had no use for `UID=Mark;PWD=sage123!;`

Of course make sure to double all the backslashes. `C:\\Documents and Settings\\All..`

Sage states that their ODBC driver has only been tested with MS Office products; but it will also work with C++, C# etc. (Per Sage support.)

With the following exception: I was unable to use a UNC path in the connection string with C# or PHP.  MS Access had no problem connecting using the UNC path. I could not make PHP work with the string. Mapped drives did not help; they might work for you.

Hints:

- Make sure to use PHP 32 bit for the Sage ODBC driver; 64 bit will not
  work!
- For testing connecting with MS Access to the ODBC driver was easy; it served as a good way to get table and field names, and confirm the
  connection string.
- I ended up setting up a web server and installing a PHP instance on the Sage server. This has the following benefits:

  - No need to install a Sage Client (500MB) on your web server.
  - Provides 32 bit option if you are running your main site in 64 bit.
  - No issues with UNC paths

Answer (score -1):

With this kind of error, you may need to ensure that only one windows profile has or been registered with the DSN name. In the other words If you have more profile registered with the same DSN name (in the same computer/server) this is most likely what cause the error!